# KendoUI MVC MultiSelect - in some cases only one return value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My KendoUI MultiSelect returns only the first selected value, if nothing was changed.

When I load the Viewpage, the MultiSelect is populated correctly with data and multiple selection. When I now proceed to save the data without having changed anything(!), the model transferred to my controller (most of the time, no pattern discernible) only contains the first selected item in the appropiate field. If I add new selections, only the first of the previously selected items is returned together with the freshly selected ones.

If I use .AutoBind(false) and then click once into the field and then outside again without having de-/selected anything, the model transferred to my controller contains the full contents on saving.

With multiple MultiSelects (on different data) on the same ViewPage, it is enough to use .AutoBind(false) on one MultiSelect (with the subsequent click like above), so that all MultiSelects suddenly return the full range of selected values.

Can anyone please explain this strange behaviour to me, possibly even with a fix?

Two different implementations in the View, which both show the same behaviour (GetDepotList() returns similar content to ViewData["DepotList"]):

```
@model List<LoadingUnitViewModel>

[...]

//Version 1
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m[i].FK_Depots)
    .Name("[" + i.ToString() + "]." + "FK_Depots")
    .Placeholder(Localize((string)ViewData["ControllerName"], "ChooseDepot"))
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Value(Model[i].FK_Depots)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetDepotList", (string)ViewData["ControllerName"]);
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "_" + i + "__FK_Depots"})
)

//Version 2
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m[i].FK_Depots)
    .Name("["+i.ToString()+"]."+"FK_Depots")
    .Placeholder(Localize((string)ViewData["ControllerName"], "ChooseDepot"))
    .BindTo(new MultiSelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["DepotList"], "Id", "Name", Model[i].FK_Depots))
 )
```

Edit:
As requested: The relevant parts of the LoadingUnitViewModel:

```
public class LoadingUnitViewModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FK_Depots")]
    public List<string> FK_Depots { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does your `LoadingUnitViewModel` look like?

Comment: Has been edited into the original post.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using AJAX binding?  I have an idea but would require not binding that way.

Comment: I'm always open to ideas. This problem has cost me more than enough time...

Comment: I have some code somewhere for this.  I'll see if  I can find it.

Answer (score 3):

We've run into some weird issues with Kendo MultiSelect and not binding to the MVC Model, I'll show you what we've done. Part of the problem looks like is the name your giving your multiselect. I dnt know why you'd need to generate multiple names like you are doing. If you give it a single name attribute you can get all the values. This is what my multiselect looks like. Notice the Name is simply "Advertisers"

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
            .Name("Advertisers")
            .BindTo(Model.Advertisers)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:445px;" })
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .Filter("startswith")
            .MinLength(5)
            .MaxSelectedItems(3)
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .AutoBind(false)                
            .Placeholder("Type the first five characters of the advertiser name...")                  
            .Value(Model.Advertisers) 
            .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:415px;"})                
            .Events(e => e.Select("advertiserSelected"))                 
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetAccounts", "CrmIntegration");
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
            })
        )
```

On form submit inside your controller, the values weren't going to the model, so instead we pulled them like this.

```
            string[] advertisers = Request.Form["Advertisers"].ToString().Split(',');
            foreach (var s in advertisers)
            {
                // access to the values in multiselect
            }
```

**Edit**
It should be noted that `default model binder` will look to bind the value to the property named in `.Name("Property")` regardless whether you use `MultiSelectFor` or not. I realized this after posting this answer.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.AdvId)
.Name("Advertisers")
 //will bind to Advertisers, not AdvId on post
```

Comment: I've tried your Request.Form, but it always has the same results as my model. If the model has multiple entries in the list, the request also returns multiple entries. If the model has only one entry, the request also returns only one entry. The name is of the form [i].name, because in some cases the view can contain multiple models (that's the reason for @model List<LoadingUnitViewModel>).